# Basic Plugin Authoring jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok so I don't really understand what's happening with the example I'm about to show. I'm creating, or rather trying to create a jQuery plugin. I'm really new to programming and seem to run into a lot of walls.

The resource page I'm on is (http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

My question is this:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

From their site works.

Now my code:

```
$.fn.dark = function() {
  this.addClass( ".panelDark");
};
$( ".panel" ).dark();
```

does not work. Can someone please help me on how to add classes in this fashion?

Attached is a jsFiddle I'm to show all the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/JFgxm/

Answer (score 2):

Typo

```
this.addClass( "panelDark");
                ^ remove . from here
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/42pzW/)</kbd>

[.addClass('ClassName')](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) not  `.addClass('.ClassName')`